# JXL datetime no need the part time

Tags: excel, datetime, cell, jxl

Hello i wrote this code to add a Date in excel but when the cell is added he show also the time. I want eliminated the time part. Thank you in advance if someone can help ..

Tabla[tabReg][tabCol]); is String Array

```
          SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
          Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(Tabla[tabReg][tabCol]);
          DateFormat df = new DateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");    
          WritableCellFormat wdf = new WritableCellFormat(df);
          cf = new WritableCellFormat(df);              
          cell = new jxl.write.DateTime(exCol,exReg, convertedDate);


          cell.setCellFormat(wdf);
          sheet2.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: try adding the cell and then changing the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put the format when you create de cell.

```
cell = new jxl.write.DateTime(exCol,exReg, convertedDate,wdf);
```